# Change Subquery to a type of JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

For the past few days, I have been trying to convert a subquery to an Inner Join since I need to migrate an SQL code to BigQuery, and the latter does not support subqueries.

This is the original query:

```
SELECT order_id_int, order_number_vc, 
(SELECT TOP 1 create_dt FROM lifecycle_tbl life WHERE life.recipient_package_id_fk_int = pak.recipient_package_id_int AND status_vc = 'Deleted' ORDER BY lifecycle_id_int DESC) AS package_archive_dt,
FROM recipient_package_tbl pak
```

I have changed it like this:

```
SELECT order_id_int, order_number_vc
FROM recipient_package_tbl pak
INNER JOIN lifecycle_tbl life
ON life.recipient_package_id_fk_int = pak.recipient_package_id_int
WHERE life.status_vc = 'Deleted'
```

Clearly, with a TOP 1 and an ORDER BY DESC, I need to only take the first value to add it to the query (through a subquery). However, if I do that directly in the INNER JOIN, it filters the entire query.

If somebody knows how to make the change correctly I will thank you so much.

Comment: You can't change the subquery to a `JOIN` on it's own, just to the `TOP (1)`. A `JOIN` on it's own won't replicate the behaviour. You could use `APPLY` to move the subquery. Otherwise you'll likely want to use a derived table or CTE around the entire query and do a "Top 1 in each group".

Comment: If BigQuery has window functions you can do a `ROW_NUMBER` solution.

Comment: Bigquery is not the same as SQL server, please correct your tags

Comment: Are you sure BigQuery doesn't support subqueries? There are examples on the Internet where they are using BigQuery with subqueries in the select clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this work for you?  I used [ROW_NUMBER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number), and broke it out into two steps for clarity.

```
with subquery as (
    SELECT life.recipient_package_id_fk_int, create_dt, row_number() over(partition by life.recipient_package_id_fk_int ORDER BY lifecycle_id_int DESC) as rn
    FROM lifecycle_tbl life 
    WHERE status_vc = 'Deleted' 
), subquery_fitlered as (
    SELECT recipient_package_id_fk_int, create_dt as package_archive_dt
    FROM subquery
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT order_id_int, order_number_vc, 
 package_archive_dt
FROM recipient_package_tbl pak
LEFT JOIN subquery_fitlered 
ON subquery_fitlered.recipient_package_id_fk_int = pak.recipient_package_id_int
```